# sencha touch 2.4 unable to get the view in the controller "MVC way with refrence"

Tags: google-maps-api-3, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I'm trying to create a small application with Google Maps API.
First, I started with a navigation view named `MainView`; this is the code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainView', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
alias: 'widget.mainView',

requires: [
    'Ext.navigation.Bar',
    'Ext.Button',
    'Ext.Panel',
    'Ext.Map'
],

config: {
    itemId: 'mynavigationview',
    navigationBar: {
        .......
        layout: {
            .....
        },
        items: [
            ......
        ]
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'Locations',
            itemId: 'mapPanel',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'map',
                    height: '100%',
                    itemId: 'map'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}});
```

Secand, in the controller `mapController` I made 3 references and 1 control `onMapInitialize` to center the map on my position with the the library `ext.util.Geolocation`. This is the code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.mapController', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
alias: 'controller.mapcontroller',

config: {
    refs: {
        mapView: {
            selector: 'mainView #map',
            xtype: 'Ext.Map'
        },
        mainView: {
            selector: 'mainView',
            xtype: 'Ext.navigation.View'
        },
        mapPanel: {
            selector: 'mainView #mapPanel',
            xtype: 'Ext.Panel'
        }
    },

    control: {
        "map#map": {
            initialize: 'onMapInitialize'
        }
    }
},

onMapInitialize: function(component, eOpts) {
    var map = this.getMapView();

    var geo = Ext.create('Ext.util.Geolocation', {
        autoUpdate: false,
        listeners: {
            locationupdate: function(geo) {
                var currentLat = geo.getLatitude();
                var currentLng =  geo.getLongitude();
                console.log('marking current location...');
                var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLat,currentLng);
                map.setCenter(currentLocation);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                    map: map,
                    position: currentLocation,
                    title: 'My Current Location'
                });
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    infoWindow.setContent('My current position');
                    infoWindow.open(this.getMap(), marker);
                });
            },
            locationerror: function(geo, bTimeout, bPermissionDenied, bLocationUnavailable, message) {
                if(bTimeout)
                    Ext.Msg.alert('Timeout occurred',"Could not get current position");
                else
                    alert('Error occurred.');
            }
        }
    });
    geo.updateLocation();
}});
```

But when  I test the application in the navigator, this error in this image has also appeared: [image: Error image]

I think that, possibly, the instance `var map = this.getMapView();` is not working or that's the wrong reference. Can anyone help?

Comment: update your code for get map object , change "var map = this.getMapView(); " to "var map = this.getMapView().getMap();"

Comment: Thanks u, it's working now :) can i get your email plz ?